# Сослагательное наклонение – как бы … (parte 2)

Tags: наклонение, сослагательное

(1) *Он присутствовал на этом вечере, **как бы присутствовал** мертвец на приготовлениях к собственным похоронам.*

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в след. пунктах:

а) *как бы* - это "цельный", "слившийся" с течением времени сравнительный союз или это союз *как* + частица *бы* как элемент сослаг. наклонения + глагольная форма на -*л*?

б) если опустить частицу *бы* для Вас как для носителей языка меняется смысл предложения? Сохраняет ли предложение оттенок ирреальности?

в) Большую трудность составляет объяснение того, почему в некотор. случаях стоит индикатив, а в некот. сослаг. наклон., если в обоих случаях речь идет о нереальных событиях.

Для контраста к предложению (1):

(2) *Он ощутил на себе взгляд физически, словно до него **дотронулись** пальцем.*

Как правильно обосновать выбор модуса в таких случаях? 
Получилось при сравнении, что в моем языке ВСЕГДА стоит сосл.накл. после сравнительного союза, а в русском анализе более 50 примеров с индикативом и только 2 с сосл. накл.

Благодарна за любую мысль, которая меня с места сдвинет!!!

Comment: Anonim, а что у вас за работа такая со сослагательным наклонением?

Comment: ... дорогой Серж, это работа, которая мне жить спокойно не дает... я учу итальянский и пишу завершительную работу в университете и мой учитель имел "замечательную" идею сравнить сосл. накл. в этих 2 языках, как в языках из разных языковых семей. мне пришлось учить русский, что ооооочень сложно и отличается от моего родного языка... не знаю, что из этого выидет, посмотрим... (так говорят в России?)  ; )

Comment: Кстати. В русском правильно будет сказать: у учителя появилась идея. Имел идею - дословный  перевод.

Comment: Да, так говорят. Кстати, для испанки Вы очень хорошо пишете и излагаете мысли.

Answer (score 2):

Союз ***как бы*** имеет значение нереальности, условности. Что касается вашего предложение, то  вторая часть, придаточная сравнительная, имеет значение сослагательное наклонения. Если изъять союз **как бы,** изменится смысл предложения: **мертвец присутствовал на похоронах( получится комичная ситуация)**. Т.е. сослагательное наклонение перейдет в изъявительное.

Во втором примере нет сослагательного наклонения, т.к речь не идет о какой-то гипотетической ситуации. Здесь имеет место реальная ситуация:  ***Т.е. две реальные ситуации: до него дотронулись и него появилось ощущение.***  **Взгляд, который он ощутил на себе, он сравнил с дотрагиванием. Действие завершено.**

> **Помните: обязательное условие для сослагательного наклонения - это частица "бы".**

1

Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения со **значением условно-предположительного сравнения, соответствуя по значению сл.: как будто.**

2.

Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения или придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения **со значением сравнения (которое представляется недостоверным),** соответствуя по значению сл.: как бы, будто бы, как если бы.

II част.
Употребляется при выражении предположительности, **условности высказывания, соответствуя по значению сл.: будто, будто бы.**

***Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000***

Comment: Серж, простите, но разве в (2) был сам акт "дотрагивания"? мое мнение, что деиствие точнее его ощущение только сравнивается... разве эту ситуацию можно считать реальной? или я не в ту сторону думаю?

Comment: Нет, смысл в том, что взгляд, который он ощутил на себе, он сравнил с дотрагиванием. Действие завершено. Т.е.речь идет о том, что было, а не о том, что могло бы быть, если бы до него дотронулись.

Comment: Я хотел написать одно, а написал другое. Спутался. Ответ исправлен.

Answer (score 1):

a) В первом предложении *неразделённое* "**как бы**" не сочетается со смыслом, который пытаются выразить (как именно он присутствовал, подобно кому), поэтому выходит нескладно - "как бы" *требует* разделения:

*Он присутствовал на этом вечере (так,) **как** присутствовал **бы** мертвец на приготовлениях к собственным похоронам.*

Использовать неразделённое "как бы" можно в значении "будто", но только изменив смысл (выразив общее впечатление от его присутствия - вместо указания на характер присутствия):

*Он присутствовал на этом вечере, но было странное впечатление: **как бы** (, будто) мертвец присутствовал на приготовлениях к собственным похоронам.*